# Disable sorting on hidden columns in bootstrap-table

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-table

I am using [bootstrap-table](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/) with the [table-multiple-sort](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/extensions/#table-multiple-sort) extension to make sortable table.

In [this example](http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/#extensions/multiple-sort.html) when you hide some columns, sorting is disabled for the hidden columns.

However, when I applied the plugin, sorting still occurs on the hidden columns. See this JS Fiddle:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r6ajuorm/16/)

```
<table ref="mainTable" className="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" cellSpacing="0" id="mainTable" data-show-toggle="true" data-show-columns="true" data-search="true" data-pagination="true">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
               <th data-field="Customer Name" data-halign="center" data-align="left" data-sortable="true">Customer Name</th>
               <th data-field="Location Type" data-halign="center" data-align="left" data-sortable="true">Location Type</th>
               <th data-field="Location" data-halign="center"
                  data-align="left" data-sortable="true">Location</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td></td>
               <td>Cap Corp</td>
               <td>Main</td>
               <td>Norwalk CT 06851</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td></td>
               <td>Cap Corp</td>
               <td>Other</td>
               <td>Norwalk CT 06851</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td></td>
               <td>Tel</td>
               <td>Main</td>
               <td>Slough SL1 4DX</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td></td>
               <td>Tel</td>
               <td>Other</td>
               <td>London W1B 5HQ</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
```

How can I disable sorting on the hidden columns?

Comment: Some of the language was ambiguous, so I've made it easier to understand the problem and intended solution. However it's still a little vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's showing because you haven't set option `sortPriority`
By setting this this will solve error.

### [Check working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/r6ajuorm/17/)

Your JS should look like this
*example taken from jsfiddle given in question.*

```
$('#mainTable').bootstrapTable({
    showFilter: true,
    showMultiSort: true,
    sortPriority: [{
        "sortName": "Location",
        "sortOrder": "desc"
    }]
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I will award your bounty in 22 hours (I can't right now). How do you know that? I didn't find it in documentation.

Comment: First I read documentation and all the links you provided, but found nothing. Then in jsFiddle I saw one error in console that `sortPriority is null`, then checked all the links you provided and found solution in [this link](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/extensions/#table-multiple-sort). That's it. Eagerly waiting for bounty.